# Allocating Array of Pointers on Heap

Tags: c++, arrays, heap-memory

Does the following create x new objects, or simply allocate space for x objects?:

```
Vector3D* binArray = new Vector3D[size];
```

I need to build an array with space for x Vector3D objects on the heap. However, a Vector3D object can only be created when an "add" function is called - this will take the parameters, construct the object on the heap and add its address to the array of Vector3D pointers.

Comment: You've called new - this means you will be calling constructors.

Comment: Use std::vector!

Answer (score 4):

This does create an array of Vector3D objects on the heap.

Each vector is created by calling the Vector3D constructor.

Put a little debugging print statement in the default constructor for Vector3D, and watch the constructor get called the same number of times as you have vectors in your array.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class C {
public:
  C() { cout << "Hello default constructor here\n"; }
};

int main() {
  C* cs = new C[5];
}
```

Output is:

```
Hello default constructor here
Hello default constructor here
Hello default constructor here
Hello default constructor here
Hello default constructor here
```

If your class does not have a default constructor, you cannot allocate the array in one shot (thank you for the comment @Everyone), so in this case consider using a `std::vector` or a `std::array` and adding your Vector3D objects dynamically ---  or even "statically"! Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Vector3D {
  double i, j, k;
public:
  Vector3D(double i, double j, double k): i(i), j(j), k(k) {}
};

int main() {
  vector<Vector3D> v = {
    Vector3D(3, 4, 5),
    Vector3D(6, 8, 10),
    Vector3D(7, 24, 25)
  };
  v.push_back(Vector3D(1, 2, 3));
  cout << v.size() << '\n';
}
```

This outputs 4.

You can also make your vector contain pointers to Vector3D objects.

Comment: I think it's worth to note that if he doesn't have a default constructor this cannot work. Just for the sake of completion.

Comment: So, how can I have an array of Vector3D objects (of size x) as a private member and then construct and allocate each object dynamically individually.

Comment: You want an array as a member but you want each of the members of the array to be on the heap? I _think_ the last edit I made should help, though to be honest, storing the Vector3D objects directly in an array, std::array, or std::vector I would think would be easy. Can you clarify (1) is the size of your array known in advance? (2) Must the Vector3D obejcts be on the heap or is it okay to be allocated by value?

Comment: @Edward use std::vector

Comment: @pm100, this is a learning exercise and we've been told not to use it.

Comment: @Edward In C++ you cannot declare an array with a variable length. Length of arrays must be obtained at compile time. That is why there is `vector`. You can declare a `std::vector<Vector3D*> binArray;` And then you can add new items and allocate them when you want. `binArray.push_back(new Vector3D(...));`

Comment: Yikes! @Edward, if you are not allowed to use std::vector or std::array, then you need to make sure `Vector3D` has a default constructor. Allocate the array like you did. All Vector3D objects will be initialized according the default constructor and you will have to overwrite them with your `add` method, or say `binarray[i] = Vector3D(x, y, z)` or similar.

Comment: @Edward This way, you can resize the `std::vector` to whatever you want and have it contain `nullptr`s as long as you didn't allocate members.

Comment: @RayToal, The size is not known before run time and the Vector3D objects must be allocated to the heap.

Comment: Then you need to use `std::vector` or overallocate and keep a counter of how many slots in your dynamically allocated binArray are actually "used."

Comment: @RayToal, What would happen if I deleted one of the slots? Would the space still exist, for me to fill it with a new object?

Comment: @Edward -- *his is a learning exercise and we've been told not to use it.* -- So be enterprising and create your own`vector` class and use that.  Not only will you learn how to do what you're asking for, you can use it for other applications, not just this one.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add based on the asker's comments on RayToal's excellent answer. If you don't know the size of the `binArray` prior to runtime then you must use `std::vector`. If you want to allocate each item alone, I would recommend using `std::vector<Vector3D*>`.

This way you can resize the `std::vector` at runtime and when you do, it will hold a bunch of `nullptr`s that are not allocated. Then you can allocate each one of them separately.

```
std::vector<Vector3D*> binArray;
binArray.resize(x);  // now you have binArray of size x and no allocated elements
binArray[0] = new Vector3D(...);
```

Please keep in mind that you need to delete them after you're not using them in order to not have a memory leak:

```
for(size_t i=0;i<binArray.size(); i++)
  if(binArray[i]!=nullptr) delete binArray[i];
```